landscaper ate some exotic fruit from my orchard
Not for legal advice and any advice is strictly to clarify my thoughts...
Located in south NJ. I have a small orchard in my backyard.
I put a lot of hard work, time & amendments as I only plant exotic &/or hard to find fruit and berries...any ways the landscaper took and ate my only asian pear that I babied for the last two years it finally produced the first harvest and still needed few more weeks on the tree. my question is can I hold this against the company as this was priceless to me as I was going to use this for a special ceremony.




What did the company say when you asked?

You say it was your only pear, but I can see at least 4 of them in the 2nd photo.

@JBentley Right? The whole thing doesn't add up. I have a feeling this special ceremony is called "fruit salad."

Did you forbid him to eat of the fruit from that tree?

God warned Adam and Eve not eat the fruit from the Tree of Knowledge. Did you warn the workers that these pears were valuable?

@JBentley this was an older picture when the tree started fruiting but didn't make it...this isn't a "pear" the ripe size and color is the size of a typical grapefruit and with a gold/brown color they typically ripen mid to end of fall

@bdb484 I'm sorry the story is confusing to you....I was trying to relay what actually happened without getting into the gardening details as this is a law group...and I figured was straight to the point...guess some here are just that

@barmar I also have a coopwith 4 chickens do I have to be worried now that I didn't think to warn them?

Conversion

Conversion is an intentional tort consisting of "taking with the intent of exercising over the chattel an ownership inconsistent with the real owner's right of possession".

You need to prove that a) the person intended to take the pear and b) they took the pear.
If you can do that, then you are entitled to damages to compensate you for your loss. Courts don’t do “priceless” so you would need to put an actual monetary value on the fruit. Market value of a replacement would be your starting point. You might be able to get a small amount for the emotional damage, possibly of the same order as the market value, however, as that is not a reasonably foreseeable consequence of the conversion, it seems very unlikely - damages are only what can be reasonably foreseen.

I do have him on camera chomping on it like he owns it

@JosephWit So you have proof but your key issue is that you can only get the market value of the fruit which will probably be a couple of dollars at most even if to you it was way more valuable.

damages are only what can be reasonably foreseen Hmm, are you sure of that, and for which jurisdiction? The eggshell skull doctrine goes directly against that, but maybe personal injury goes by different rules. In France, the test is objective value, not what could be foreseen (what is the "objective value" of an object made unique by sentimental attachment is left as an exercise for the ~~reader~~ court.)

@UJM there is a definite tension between the doctrines of reasonable foreseeability and the eggshell skull (see https://classic.austlii.edu.au/au/journals/JCULawRw/2001/6.pdf). Eggshell skull is a doctrine that allows pushing beyond reasonable foreseeability but it is usually applied only to personal injury, not property damage.


my question is can I hold this against the company as this was priceless to me as I was going to use this for a special ceremony.

The court would need to interpret the claim of pricelessness against the fact that you left the fruit outside, unguarded, unfenced, seemingly around a children's play area, and within the access of a strange workman who was not advised of its special value or importance.
Given that the workman was on the land lawfully and in that area of the property legitimately, and given the common practice of maintaining fruit-growing trees in a private garden without attaching value to the fruit and whilst being willing to distribute any fruit freely, I'm inclined to think this does not meet the criteria of a theft.
I would consider it the analogy of helping himself to tap water to fill his own bottle, or helping himself to a lollipop from a basket of them placed out, or plucking an acorn from a tree so as to throw it playfully at a colleague.
They are not necessarily actions to which a person should feel entitled, but they are also things that are generally permitted, and so may be done thoughtlessly.
As such I don't think it's something that could be "held against" the company in a substantial way.
You could certainly complain and express annoyance.
If the matter was pressed then I think a court would find the appropriation cheeky from a workman, and more important to set the principle that such appropriations from someone else's land are done at the risk of the taker having to make good if the owner is not minded to allow it.
But the valuation of any damages would be limited to the market value of the fruit or replacement in kind, not the sentimental value to you of the individual fruit which was consumed. So from the case you'd squeeze very little.

this is in my backyard the orchard is fenced in and not part of the contract.

@JosephWit, it's very difficult to see the fencing or enclosure from the photographs you've posted - it appears to just be trees at the periphery of a large garden. You said the workman was a landscaper, so he hasn't just walked in off the street - by which I mean, he hasn't passed through what a stranger to the premises would regard as an unambiguous boundary and into an exclusive area where he had no business.

It certainly meets the criteria of theft: taking fruit off a tree without a specific permission is no different from helping yourself to your host's silverware. But its very much de minimis (i.e. so trivial as to be below the notice of the judicial system).

@PaulJohnson, an act such as stealing fruit from a tree certainly could meet the criteria of theft, but I'm not clear a jury would find dishonesty in the act in this particular context. Silverware doesn't grow on trees wild, get left to rot on the ground, or get handed to visitors and neighbours - it's more plausible to seize a fruit from a tree thoughtlessly than to seize silverware.

I appreciate everyones coments in helping me think this through. although I might not go to court with this I'm definitely going to bring this up to management and although some just see a fruit was eaten I have spent hours over the course of the last couple years taking care of this and I have tons of pux and video too but won't overwhelm this chat with it

@JosephWit, for my part I fully understand the sentimental value, but left unchecked people tend to become increasingly particular and fussy about what is sentimental, whilst also becoming increasingly careless about costly protections and maintenance behaviours in spaces that occasionally have to be shared, and it can lead to chippiness and incivility. You have to remember what other people would have regarded as the likely importance of the fruit, and what value and vested labour that unpicked fruits typically have in our everyday experience.

@steve I hear what you're saying but this is my property I own every grain of sand and even if there's an empty water bottle if it's on PRIVATE property you are stealing and nothing cand justify that

@JosephWit, but in reality visitors do justify using or consuming things on private property without always explicit permission. Tap water, toilet paper, and so on. You're working yourself up into a hard-line position that you've been a victim of a theft, when in reality the workman plucked what appeared to be naturally growing produce of no value and in the open. Nobody has denied your property rights, what I'm saying is that you need to be reasonable about communicating with invited strangers about how things work on your property - a misunderstanding is not a criminal offence.
